# 2 queries for my website

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently I have a htaccess working with only 1 query.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

it does is make my website look like `example.com/thispage` instead of `example.com/index.php?page=thispage`, but I would like to add a blogging feature for my website, thus making the url allow `example.com/blog/1` instead of `example.com/index.php?page=blog&blogid=1` - any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip existing files and directories from rewrite rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# blog page
RewriteRule ^(blog)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&blogid=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

# remaining pages
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the path inside php. inside php you could say something like the following

```
// Explode the parts by slash
$path = explode('/', $_GET['page']);
// First part found should be the base page, fallback to home
$page = isset($path[0]) ? $path[0] : 'home';
if ($page === 'blog') {
    // On blog, if 2nd part is provided it's a blog item ID
    // Otherwise fallback to null, should show blog overview page
    $blogId = isset($path[1]) ? $path[1] : null;
}
```

This is just a basic example, this could be done much more advanced and prettier.
For example you could look at laravel routing.

Writing multiple rules inside htaccess is harder for maintainability and portability to other systems like nginx. (speaking out of experience :p)